"Go to Wiki" doesn't go to wiki for c# tag
When on C#-tag page I see a Go to Wiki button.

Clicking it will go to C-tag page instead of showing wiki. For C-tag button works correctly.
Don't recall I've seen such button before, when was it changed and why I am not informed?
You need to fire your testers, really =D

It seems that that '#' causes the problem, I get the same effect with the [tag:f#] tag.

"You need to fire your testers, really =D" - we are the testers, and they can't fire someone that doesn't work for them :')

Behaviour almost consistent with the new Jobs. They just need to do the same for C++.

"when was it changed and why I am not informed" here it is. I don't know how you missed it - it's just an update of a post on another site, where the post is two months old. Impossible to miss!

@VLAZ, thanks, such an amazing way to inform users about feature in form of post update in some heavily downvoted and long time forgotten topic. Feels like a revenge =D

That's about standard recently, @Sinatr . The "announcement" for the recent CSS change was posted as an answer to an over 2 year old question...

(not related) Where is the top users link for the tag now? I can't find it anymore

@PeterHaddad at the right side of the tag info page there's a "Top Answerers" section at the bottom of which is a "more" link which leads to the top users page.

As was described in Cafce25's answer we indeed messed up the URL path here. That is now fixed and should no longer be an issue with this or potentially any other tag wikis.

The problem is evident if you look at the link of the 'C tag page' you copied to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#/info as you can see it's actually linking c# with an unescaped #, everything after it will be interpreted as fragment instead of as part of the URL path. Properly URL-escaping the octothorpe does make the link work: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info

Also note that if you go to the tag, it's already escaped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23. It's just the link on "Go to Wiki" that have URL encoding.
